# How to split a matrix, represented as a list of list, in half?

Tags: python

If I have a matrix represented as a list of list how do I split it down the middle.

For example

```
[[1,1,1,1,1,1], ,[2,2,2,2,2,2], ,[3,3,3,3,5,6]]
```

would be

```
[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [[1,1,1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3,5,6]]

>>> [[sub_list[:len(sub_list) // 2] for sub_list in my_list], 
     [sub_list[len(sub_list) // 2:] for sub_list in my_list]]
[[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 5, 6]]]
```